# Promises from a service into a controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

This is probably down to me not fully understanding promises in angular. I just can't see where.

I have this service:

```
getSingleEventById : function(eventId)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $localForage.getItem('PublicEvents').then(function(results){
            var found = $filter('filter')(results, {eventId: eventId}, true);
            if (found.length) 
            {
                deferred.resolve({'event':found[0]});
                return deferred.promise;
            } else {
                return deferred.reject('not found');
            }
        });
    },
```

being called from a controller:

```
    $scope.event = myService.getSingleEventById($stateParams.eventId).then(function(foundEvent){
        return foundEvent;
})
```

What i am seeing in the output is:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Where am i going wrong with my promise in my service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need make `getSingleEventById` method return Promise object. So simply return result of `then` call.

Also you can improve your code by getting rid of redundant `deferred` object. You don't need it because whatever you return from `then` callbacks becomes new Promise object, which is passed into next `then` in queue.

```
getSingleEventById: function (eventId) {
    return $localForage.getItem('PublicEvents').then(function (results) {
        var found = $filter('filter')(results, {eventId: eventId}, true);
        if (found.length) {
            return {event: found[0]};
        }
        return $q.reject('not found');
    });
},
```

Note how you return `return {event: found[0]};` object. This is equivalent to previous `deferred.resolve({'event':found[0]});` however without creating one more intermediate `deferred` object.

Comment: Thanks so much, that sorted it!

Answer (score 1):

```
getSingleEventById : function(eventId)
    {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $localForage.getItem('PublicEvents').then(function(results){
            var found = $filter('filter')(results, {eventId: eventId}, true);
            if (found.length) 
            {
                deferred.resolve({'event':found[0]});

            } else {
                deferred.reject('not found');
            }
        });

       return deferred.promise; // return the promise here
    }
```